# What should our FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion

From [The 7 Essential Meta Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), it's important to figure out what the FAQ section should contain.  This is really referencing the first part that mentions types of questions that are explicitly on-topic or off-topic.  It's important to answer this so we know what kind of site we want this to be.

Comment: I think we definitely need a section on how to answer a hand history question.

Answer (score 2):

I think a glossary in the FAQ would be great for common acronyms and less common terms.  If we want to do it as a community wiki question that would be fine too so long as it is linked to from the FAQ.

Comment: This is really important, as I have no idea half of these abbreviations!

Comment: @Wil We have an abbreviation thread going, we should convert it to a wiki at some point. See http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/142/is-there-a-comprehensive-source-for-poker-terminology

Answer (score 1):

I think we will need a guide to how to post a good hand history, including whatever markdown we get for suit/card images.

A guide as to what constitutes enough specificity would be good too.  For instance,

> How do I play AA under the gun?

^ bad

> $1/2 Live game, short-stacked AA UTG decision
>
> I was UTG with a 50bb stack in a $1/2 game, and got dealt aces.  The table had been pretty loose-passive pre-flop, but the player 3 to my left had recently sat down and started raising much more often pre-flop.  Should I try to limp/reraise, since the player to my left might raise and generate a lot of dead money from calls, or should I just raise to open?

^ better

A helpful guide:
[FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: I'd argue that the FAQ should do more than give examples like this though, to help people understand what parts of the later make it better. It should specifically note that they should include as much information as they can about the situation, including the stakes, their stack size, their position, the stack sizes of their opponents, the history of the table as a whole and of any specific opponents who are involved in the hand, etc.

Comment: Right, I wouldn't consider those examples a guide, rather they are examples that would be included to illustrate the points of the guide.